# calling different class objects based on value of string

Tags: java, android, string

I have a string (str) that holds the class name and want to call a method of that class based on the string value how do i achieve this?

Ex.

if str = "classA" i want call the method classA.domatrix() 
if str = "classB" then classB.domatrix()

Comment: what is classA? Is it an Activity class? and what is domatrix a static method??

Comment: find something about java reflection .

Comment: classA is just any java class and domatrix can be a static method.

Comment: @v1kas any java class even activity class?

Answer (score 2):

This may help

```
String str = "ClassA";
Class.forName(str).newInstance();
```

Note : it should have a default no-arg constructor. Prepend the package name of the class as well.

Answer (score 0):

you can do

```
if(str.equals("ClassA"))
ClassA.domatrix();
else if(str.equals("ClassB"))
ClassB.domatrix();
```

we cannot use switch here because switch does not work on string but latest version of jdk support string in switch case.

or the other solution is to use `enum`.

Comment: this works fine when i have two calsses what if i have hundreds of calsses?

Comment: then either you have to use switch case or define an enum and then use in switch case.